# Display a content in browser from my Django rest framework on my BotUI

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-rest-framework, xmlhttprequest, chatbot

I'm working on a simple demo on botui. I am trying to fetch information from my API.
i used the xmlHttpRequest

```js
var loadsmth,
  botui= new BotUI('stars-bot'),
  API = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/stocks/';

function xhr(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET',API);
  xhr.onload = ()=> {
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.response)
    console.log(data)
  };
  xhr.send();
```

i seem to be stuck on trying to get a response.. please help complete my code

Comment: do you see some request in your browser network in dev platform ?

Comment: requests like what @yehonatanyehezkel

Comment: you need to understood first where is the problem - in the server side ( django ) or in the client side ( browser javascript )  so see first in the browser develoer console ->network tab - waht happen after you call your function "xhr"  what is the server respnse ( if any)